# How to make antlr 4 runtime as an osgibundle?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I have created a eclipse plugin and converted it to maven,which needs the dependency of antlr but when the plugin execute it says it cant find the required package. Then i came to know anltr is not osgi bundle. any one please tell me how to convert the antlr jar file into an osgi bundle.? The antlr dependency must support my mvenized eclipse plugin

Answer (score 1):

The main ANTLR 4 project doesn't support this (see [issue #689](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/689)). However, I've recently created an [independent fork](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4) of the project which aims to target a number of issues related to the use of ANTLR 4 in large(r)-scale and/or performance-critical applications. One of the items I'd like to implement is using OSGi for improved runtime versioning instead of the [manual mechanism](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuntimeMetaData.java) currently in place. I recommend filing an issue with this fork of the project so I can include these changes as part of my initial release.

https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/issues